# Setting max date in .NET DateTimePicker causes drop down calendar to show wrong date

Tags: .net, winforms, controls, datetimepicker

If you use a .NET DateTimePicker with the maximum date set to an earlier date than today when the user clicks the button for the calendar to drop down the calendar defaults to the first day of the current month instead of the day already selected in the control (as would be correct behaviour).

I believe that this is happening due to the fact that the control can't find todays date in the available date range. Could someone please confirm if this is true and possibly give me a work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same behaviour here, looks like a bug to me. 
So far, no workaround unfortunately.

Comment: Does microsoft know about this bug? any plans to fix it?

Comment: @Nagg: Don't know. I didn't submit a bug report for it, and don't know (nor searched) if anyone has.